# JXA: Create a mailbox in Apple Mail

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I am trying to create a sub-mailbox in Apple Mail using JavaScript.

I have the following code snippet (parent is a reference to the mailbox in which I want the new mailbox):

```
var mb = mail.Mailbox({name: "SubFolder"});
parent.mailboxes.push(mb);
```

The events log shows:

```
app = Application("Mail")
 app.mailboxes.byName("Local").mailboxes.byName("Archive").mailboxes.push(app.Mailbox({"name":"SubFolder"}))

    --> Error -10000: AppleEvent handler failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Craig.

Code now:

```
var mb = mail.Mailbox({name: "Local/Archive/Test Archive/SubFolder"})
logger.logDebug("mb = '" + Automation.getDisplayString(mb) + "'.");
mail.mailboxes.push(mb)                     // create the subfolder
```

This works as long as there are no spaces in the path.
I tried to force the space using \\ in front of it, but then you get "Test\ Archive" as the name.

So how do I get a space in the name to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To create a sub-folder, you need a name  like a posix path --> `"/theMasterMailbox/subMailBox1/subMailBox2/subMailBox3"`.

---

So, you need:

- A loop to put the name of each parent folder into an array.
- Use `join('/')` to join the elements of an array  into a string.
- Use `mail.mailboxes.push(mb)` instead of `parent.mailboxes.push(mb)`

---

Here's a sample script which creates a mailbox named "**SubFolder**" in the selected folder (the mailbox):

```
mail = Application('com.apple.Mail')
parent = mail.messageViewers()[0].selectedMailboxes()[0]

mboxNames = [parent.name()]
thisFolder = parent
try {
    while (true) { // loop while exists the parent folder 
        mboxNames.unshift(thisFolder.container().name()) // add the name of the parent folder to the beginning of an array
        thisFolder = thisFolder.container() // get the parent of thisFolder
    }
} catch (e) {} // do nothing on error, because thisFolder is the top folder

mboxNames.push("SubFolder") // append the name of the new subFolder to the array

mBoxPath = mboxNames.join('/') // get a string (the names separated by "/")
mb = mail.Mailbox({name:mBoxPath})
mail.mailboxes.push(mb) // create the subfolder
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just seen this as I was not notified when you posted. I'll try this in a sandbox and see if I can get it to work for local box.

Comment: See extension to my post above. I cannot get it to work if there are spaces in one of the mailbox names.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer (`macOS Sierra`, **Version 10.12.6**).
Sorry ,I cannot help you.

Comment: I'm also on 10.12.6. I gave up and removed the spaces from my mailbox names. Archiver script is now working.